# Why is my program not reading the user input?

Tags: java

I am asking the user to put a radius number but the 
program is not reading the user input I mean it will let
me put the numbers but doesn't take it and calculate?
I don't know where I made a mistake?

I string the radius and I put 
radius=input.nextLine(); 
where I Want the user to put his/her input 
but when I run it the program doesn't 
calculate the user input.
 Please help thanks.

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    public class TComparable  
{
    private double radius;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        int option;
        String radius;

        option = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
        while(option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        {    
            // Declare and initialize two geometric objects
            Circle1 circle1 = new Circle1(5);
            Circle1 circle2 = new Circle1(4);

            System.out.println("What is the radius of the two circle:");

            radius=input.nextLine();
            radius=input.nextLine();


            Circle1 circle = (Circle1)GeometricObject1.max(circle1, circle2);
            System.out.println("The max circle's radius is " + circle.getRadius());

            System.out.println(circle);
            System.out.println("The two objects have the same area? " +
                equalArea(circle1,circle2));

            displayGeometricObject(circle1);

            displayGeometricObject(circle2);
            option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, "Would you like to continue?");
        }

    }

    public static boolean equalArea(GeometricObject1 object1,
    GeometricObject1 object2) 
    {
        return object1.findArea() == object2.findArea();
    }

    public static void displayGeometricObject(GeometricObject1 object) 
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The area is " + object.findArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter is " + object.findPerimeter());
    }
}
```

Comment: `int status= ` _what,_ exactly?

Comment: I was just practicing and put it accidentally thanks

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You don't seem to be doing anything with the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one problem straight up. If you're asking for two radii, you probably want to store them both rather than overwrite the first with the second:

```
System.out.println("What is the radius of the two circle:");
radius=input.nextLine();
radius=input.nextLine();
```

And, though you *input* the radii, I see no code that affects the circles based on those radii. I'd expect to see something like:

```
circle1.setRadius(radius1); // after converting string to numeric of course.
```

Without that, your circles will stay at the same radius they were initialised with, presumably `4` and `5`.

In terms of more concrete code, assuming that the `Circle1` class *does* have a `setRadius(double)` member function, you could use something like:

```
System.out.println("What is the radius of the two circle:");

radius = input.nextDouble(); // may want to catch exception
circle1.setRadius(radius);

radius = input.nextDouble(); // ditto
circle2.setRadius(radius);
```

Comment: I am trying to put two numbers that is why

Comment: @David, you _do_ get two numbers. You store the first one in `radius` and then you store the _second_ one in `radius`, overwriting the first. Not that it matters, since you never actually _use_ those radii to affect the circles anyway :-)

Comment: How do I be able to use the input to affect the program

Comment: @David, read the second part of my answer. The `Circle1` class should hopefully have a member function that can change the radius. Otherwise you'll need to defer creation of the circles until _after_ you have the radius.

Comment: you are right that is whats happening to my program I am just having a problem how to put a new radius and run it.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to input.nextLine() being called twice, skipping over the first input.  Instead, assign input.nextLine() to another variable, instead of setting radius again.

Comment: I did that the output is the same